# Java PreparedStatement Wilcard doesn't work

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I have DDBB with a table `users` and I'm trying to get fields `user_id` and `user_pass` by searching for `user_name`.
So, when I run the following query:

```
SELECT `user_id`, `user_pass` FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` LIKE '%aName%';
```

It returns, ie aName = "John":

```
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | user_pass |
+---------+-----------+
|    5    |  "1234"   |
+---------+-----------+
```

Ok, then I want to perform this using a PreparedStatement, for that reason I have made this function:

```
private final String QUERY_GETUSERNAME2 =
        "SELECT `user_id`, `user_fname`"
        + " FROM `users`"
        + " WHERE `user_fname` LIKE ?;";

private String[][] getUsersInv(String usrName){
    ArrayList<String[]> alAux = new ArrayList();
    String[][] ret = null;
    try{
        PreparedStatement st = _conn.prepareStatement(QUERY_GETUSERNAME2);
        st.setString(1, "'%"+usrName+"%'");
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            String[] asAux = {String.valueOf(rs.getInt(1)), rs.getString(2)};
            alAux.add(asAux);
        }//while
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }finally{
        if (!alAux.isEmpty()){
            ret = new String[alAux.size()][alAux.get(0).length];
            for (int i = 0; i < alAux.size(); i++)
                ret[i] = alAux.get(i);
        }//fi
    }
    return ret;
}
```

As you can see, the function returns a String[][], so I check in a previous function if returns is or not null:

```
public void insertUsersInvTableModel(JTable table, String user){
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    String[][] row = getUsersInv(user);
    if (row != null)
        model.addRow(row);
}
```

And this function is call from the listener for a JButton:

```
private void addUserActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    if (comboUsers.getSelectedIndex() != 0){
        new Users(_conn).insertUsersInvTableModel(_target, String.valueOf(comboUsers.getSelectedItem()));
        _target.validate();
        _target.repaint();
        setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

As you can imagine, there's a JDialog with a JComboBox with all the users listed down.
As table `users` is AUTO_INCREMENT, the `user_id` has some gaps (or maybe it will have), and the only way to build the JComboBox was without relate `user_id` to JComboBox index.

But, the problem is that whenever I pick an item from the JComboBox, and I run the process to get the `user_id` and `user_pass` based on the item selected (nor the index), the ResultSet is always NULL.

Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: can you post the generated query ?

Comment: @Stephan iirc this is not possible because the prepared statement is sent to db together with the parameters. there is no query string generated on java side

Comment: @MarcoForberg thx for clearing that up , i didn't use prepared statements before

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That doesn't produce a risk of SQL injection, the problem is the quotes in his parameter value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
st.setString(1, "'%"+usrName+"%'");
```

with

```
st.setString(1, "%"+usrName+"%");
```

The single quotes are automatically added by the `PreparedStatement`. With the Quotes the query will look for the String `'%usrname%'` instead of `%usrname%`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
st.setString(1, "%"+usrName+"%");
```

instead of

```
st.setString(1, "'%"+usrName+"%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION
As Marco Forberg pointed, quotes used for envolve the string parameter (') are not compulsory. Removing them fix the issue.